# Having trouble understanding this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, variables, sql-update

Basically I can't understand what this query below does:

```
UPDATE @so_stockmove 
SET  @total_move_qty = total_move_qty = (
          CASE WHEN @so_docdt_id <> so_docdt_id THEN 0 
          ELSE ISNULL(@total_move_qty, 0) 
          END
          ) + ISNULL(move_qty,0),
     balance = so_qty - @total_move_qty,
     @so_docdt_id = so_docdt_id
```

I only can guess that it updates each row for the columns `total_move_qty`,`balance`,`so_docdt_id`.

Can someone explain to me in detail what the query means:

```
UPDATE tbl SET @variable1 = columnA = expression
```

Comment: This is called **quirky update**. This is not guaranteed to work, and I will never use this method in production.

Comment: This is a horrible way of coding SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**
After reading @MotoGP comments, I did some digging and found [this article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/68467/) by [Jeff Moden](https://mvp.microsoft.com/en-us/PublicProfile/4020758?fullName=jeff%20moden) where he states the following:

> **Warning:**
>   Well, sort of. Lots of folks (including some of the "big" names in the SQL world) warn against and, sometimes, outright condemn the
>   method contained in this article as "unreliable" & "unsupported". One
>   fellow MVP even called it an "undocumented hack" on the fairly recent
>   "24 hours of SQL". Even the very core of the method, the ability to
>   update a variable from row to row, has been cursed in a similar
>   fashion. Worse yet, except for the ability to do 3 part updates (SET
>   @variable = columnname = expression) and to update both variables and
>   columns at the same time, there is absolutely no Microsoft
>   documentation to support the use of this method in any way, shape, or
>   form. In fact, even Microsoft has stated that there is no guarantee
>   that this method will work correctly all the time.
>
> Now, let me tell you that, except for one thing, that's ALL true. The
>   one thing that isn't true is its alleged unreliability. That's part of
>   the goal of the article... to prove its reliability (which really
>   can't be done unless you use it. It's like proving the reliability of
>   the SELECT statement). At the end of the article, make up your own
>   mind. If you decide that you don't want to use such a very old ,yet,
>   undocumented feature, then use a Cursor or While loop or maybe even a
>   CLR because all of the other methods are just too darned slow. Heh...
>   just stop telling me that it's an undocumented hack... I already know
>   that and, now, so do you. ;-)

**First edition**

Well, this query updates columns `total_move_qty` and `balance` in a table variable called `@so_stockmove`, and in the same time sets values to the variables called `@total_move_qty` and `@so_docdt_id`.

I didn't know it's possible to assign values to more then one target this way in Sql server (`@variable1 = columnA = expression`) but apparently that is possible.

Here is my test:

```
declare @bla char(1)

declare @tbl table
(
    X   char(1)
)

insert into @tbl VALUES ('A'),('B'), ('C')

SELECT *
FROM @tbl

UPDATE @tbl 
SET @Bla = X = 'D'

SELECT *
FROM @tbl

SELECT @bla
```

Results:

```
X -- first select before update
----
A
B
C


X -- second select after update
----
D
D
D

---- select the variable value after update
D
```

Comment: can you test if 'D' was a column from another table?

Comment: and if its possible, if X was also another column

Comment: @JoshuaRajandiran - This method is not guaranteed to work

Comment: @MotoGP this code is from a real database and its been used to create numerous report files in accounting

Answer (score 0):

It just sets the value to the variable and updates the field.